# How to add Game Over image and play again function in Flappy Bird PyGame when sprite collides?

Tags: python, pygame, flappy-bird-clone

I am doing a flappy bird PyGame project for a computer science class. I have the main code, but when the bird collides with a pipe or the ground, it just stops. I want to add a "Game Over" image (I have the PNG) and an option to play again. I think below is the part of the code that I need to add to. What should I add to make it work?

```
if (pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bird_group, ground_group, False, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask) or
        pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bird_group, pipe_group, False, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)):
    pygame.mixer.music.load(hit)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    # play again
    GAMEOVER = pygame.image.load('assets/sprites/gameover.png')
    GAMEOVER = pygame.transform.scale(GAMEOVER, (0,0))
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a variable that indicates the state of the game. Draw the scene depending on the state of this variable:

```py
GAMEOVER = pygame.image.load('assets/sprites/gameover.png')
game_state = "play"

run = True
while run:
    event_list = pygame.event.get()
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.qUIT:
            run = False

    if game_state == "play":
        for event in event_list:
            # game events
            # [...]

        # draw game
        # [...]

        if (pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bird_group, ground_group, False, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask) or
            pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bird_group, pipe_group, False, False, pygame.sprite.collide_mask)):
            pygame.mixer.music.load(hit)
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
            game_state == "game over"

    elif game_state == "game over":
        for event in event_list:
            # game over events
            # [...]

        screen.blit(GAMEOVER, (0, 0))

    pygame.display.update()
```